# Symfony2 - routing php app from vendor

Tags: php, symfony, routes, vendor

I would like to route php script from Vendor.
I used Composer to instal database managment (https://github.com/vrana/adminer/).
Source of that app is: vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php

I would like to create router to use this app, for example when I call url myweb.com/adminer,
it should load that source: vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php

Is it possible to do it via routing.yml ? Something like this:

```
adminer:
    resource: "Vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php"
    prefix:   /adminer
```

Or how it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible via symfonys `routing.yml`, since this needs the app kernel to be started, which is in `app.php`. But you can just set up adminer as another server.

If you use **apache** for example write in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/local`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.adminer
    DocumentRoot /YourPathToAdminer
    DirectoryIndex adminer.php
    <Directory /YourPathToAdminer>
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

And in your `/etc/hosts` add somewhere

```
127.0.0.1       local.adminer
```

Just call `http://local.adminer` in your browser and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy.

Create regular route and then include adminer.php and return it from controller. Do not forget to put this route under firewall

In controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
public function mysqlClientAction() {
    return new Response(include_once $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/Resources/views/adminer.php');
}
```

in routing.yml

```
admin_mysql_manager:
    path: /mysqlclient
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle\Controller\YourController::mysqlClientAction}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar through template but I have czech version, only one file:

//app/Resources/views/adminer.html.php

```
<?php
    include(__DIR__.'/../../../vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php');
 ?>
```

and route from Controler

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;    

/**
 * @Route("/adminer", name="adminer")
 * @Template(engine="php")
 */
public function adminerAction()
{
    return $this->render('::adminers.html.php');
}
```

and put adminer.php and rename into /vendor/vrana/adminer/adminer/index.php
Now address is yoursite/adminer